# newest records are entering in first row of mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using auto-increment in mysql tables and when i am entering new values in record they should come below the present row but they are coming at the first row and present records are moving one row down.
This is the part of code where i am inserting values in node.js. Employer_id is set to auto_increment.

```
  bcrypt.hash(employer_password, 10, function(err, hash) {                 
    connection.query("insert into fyp_employers(Employer_id,Employer_Fname,Employer_Lname,Email_Address,Employer_Address,Employer_City,Employer_Password,Employer_CNIC,Employer_Contact) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
        [null,employer_fname,
        employer_lname,employer_email,employer_address,Employer_City,hash,employer_cnic,employer_number],function(err){
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else
        response.send("successful");
        }); 
    });
```

[This is mysql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qsn67.png)

Comment: there is not a default order by in sql  ...  if you wat see some result in preferred  order then use order by at the end of your select query..